# Adding React elements to a static website not working

Tags: reactjs

Hi I've built a static website using HTML and CSS and I want to add some react elements to it. I've looked at the react documentation and it says all I need is:

```
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="react.js"></script>
```

The links are in the index file before the body section ends.

In the react file all I have is a simple paragraph to make sure the connection works, but nothing appears on the page at all.

```
   import React from "react"
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
    
    // JSX
    ReactDOM.render(<div><h1>Hello world!</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>, document.getElementById("react"))
```

I've downloaded the react app files and node.js as well, and I can get that working for a new project. But I just want to make a website I already have a little more robust. What am I missing here?

Comment: JSX cannot be interpreted by browsers. You will need babel to transpile the JSX into plain Javascript. And, the JS code would then work.

Comment: @Nishant The Babel Standalone OP is using can transpile the JSX on the client-side. The problem here is that it needs to be properly connected to the script tag.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Learned something new. I thought you had to transpile before sending to the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

(1) Don't try to import - the unpkg scripts have already put those library properties onto the window

(2) Use `type="text/babel"` so that Babel Standalone knows to parse the script there using its parser - you don't want the browser itself to try to parse it as standard JS:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="react.js"></script>
```

Full contents of `react.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div><h1>Hello world!</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>, document.getElementById("react"))
```

Note that:

> But I just want to make a website I already have a little more robust

Parsing JSX on the client-side is computationally expensive. Having the React functionality is surely nice, but even introducing such a small `Hello world` example requires quite a lot of overhead. For something professional, I'd highly recommend transpiling with Node beforehand.

Comment: Thank you this solved this issue. I read more about this and it seems that for a production level project I would need to pre-compile the react file into standard javascript?